# Jquery expando: "jQuery321017184022590797698", o que é isso?

Tags: jquery

Observando o objeto window pelo comando, claro com jQuery carregado na página:

```
console.log (window);
```

Temos a propriedade **function $**, conhecida como jQuery global pra quem o usa, percebo que existe a propriedade **expando** seu valor e sempre **jQueryxxxxxx** onde **x** é uma sequencia de números aleatórios quando carregamos a página!

Suponho que isto e como se fosse uma chave de integridade gerada no carregamento atual.

**Mas na verdade o que é isso?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**jQuery.expando** gera esse valor do tipo **string 'jQuery' + uniqueid** (um valor único)

Até a **versão 1.4.4**, o uniqueid é current timestamp.

A partir da **versão 1.5.1**, o uniqueid é version + Math.random () com pontos substituídos. Para ser exato é usado a seguinte lógica que gera essa string:

```
"jQuery" + (version + Math.random ()).replace (/\D/g, "")
```

**Element[ jQuery.expando ]** é um valor **int / chave** onde o **objeto** é armazenado em **jQuery.cache**;

**jQuery.cache** é um objeto que armazenará os valores de dados dos elementos da página;

**jQuery.cache[ Element[ jQuery.expando ] ]** é a representação do elemento em forma ou tipo objeto.

Para mim foi esclarecedor =D!

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7200722/jquery-expando-properties/7201455

Veja [aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/JrvNB/1/) um teste com a versão jQuery 1.6.2.